# Ошибка array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array

Tags: php, yii2

Чем вызвана ошибка array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array?

```
var_dump($newPhone);
var_dump($oldPhone); 
$toInsert = array_filter(array_diff($newPhone, $oldPhone));
```

В массивах приходят данные вот такого формата.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=&gt;
  string(10) "2222222222"
  [1]=&gt;
  string(10) "2222222222"
}
array(2) {
  [28]=&gt;
  string(10) "2222222222"
  [29]=&gt;
  string(10) "2222222222"
}
```

Причем когда ставишь die после этого кода, то все отрабатывает, но когда пытаешься запустить код целиком выходит ошибка. Именно в это место и в этой строке... как можно понять чем она вызвана?
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: позвольте вам не поверить - ошибка однозначно говорит, что передан не массив, проверьте буковки, например

Comment: полный текст ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: @Kirill добавил скрин с ошибкой, но мне кажется он ясности не даст. Тут скорей всего весь код нужен для анализа(

Comment: Предполагаю что код отрабатывает по каким то причинам два раза и по этой причине когда код отрабатывает не происходит заполнение массива. По каким причинам так происходит, так пока и не понял.... Разбираюсь...

Comment: $this->phone точно возвращает массив? Не может вдруг случиться, что там объект? через ArrayHelper:map не пропускали?

Comment: @Kirill да там точно массив, но вся петрушка в том что код отрабатывает нормально, то есть данные заносяться в БД. Незнаю как но как я писал выше код отрабатывает несколько раз и после того как он срабатывает второй раз не происходит заполнения этого массива. Как поймать эту ошибку ума не приложу. ПС код должен отработать один раз.

Comment: xdebug пользуетесь? пробрякайте строчку 136

Comment: @Kirill C:\Server\data\htdocs\rest\backend\models\CatCounterparties.php:137:
array (size=2)
  0 => string '2222222222' (length=10)
  1 => string '' (length=0)